# Mass Delete Global Value Set Values

Tags: global-picklist

Is there (what's the most efficient) way to mass delete Global Value Set values?

Removing/Replacing them manually one by one in the UI is not acceptable. I thought I might be able to do it via destructiveChanges with ant, but I am not sure if you can specifically delete certain values and not the whole set.

I also thought about deleting and deploying again, though it's a bit too late as it's referenced by quite a few picklists in the system.

Comment: Did you want to delete them, or just inactivate them?

Comment: Deactivating is easy, I want to delete them

Comment: I tried to do a destructiveChanges.xml for `GlobalPicklistValue`. It failed with the message "Entity type 'GlobalPicklist' is not available for delete in this api version". Which is odd considering I was trying to delete a GlobalPicklistValue.

Comment: That's confusing. I also had no luck at deleting with destructive changes, waiting on Salesforce support to see what they say

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any native way or Solution but when when I done some search I found a [Idea mass delete picklist values (setup)](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bp3fAAC).Which you can vote.

There I also found a Solution(Hack) which you can use in your use case.
From the original Answer.

> There is an extension in Google Chrome called "Snap Links Lite." It is
>   a great tool (I use daily anyways). Essentially it allows you to hold
>   right click on the mouse and drag a select box over anything that
>   contains a hyperlink. So, if there are 10 hyperlinks that you want
>   opened in new tabs, instead of manually clicking "open in new tab"
>   this select box will open them for you.
>
> Now, if we use this select box on the "Del" hyperlink of the picklist
>   values, it opens another tab (and for whatever reason overrides the
>   "are you sure" dialog box), and when the original screen is refreshed
>   the picklist values are deleted! All you have to do then is close the
>   tabs opened with snap links. I deleted 40 values in 15 seconds.

Many user successfully use it. Here is a extension link for your help. Which you can try.

[Snap Links Lite](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/snap-links-lite/ighmoimpbimbhbahbpcapifcplnblhgo?hl=en-GB)

Comment: This is the correct answer as of Summer '17. You can inactive values through the Metadata API, but the UI is the only way to to delete the picklist values.

Comment: I can confirm this, Salesforce support responded with "I believe it is not possible to actually purge the inactive values from a globalValueSet."

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of value in Global Value set, then Salesforce UI is boring to do it. Using Workbench, you can easily replace or update Global value set. So, Just add a single value using REST API. It will remove all the value add one value. Then you have to just remove the single one. Just two simple steps are here:

First, Go to Rest Explorer from Workbench and Find the ID of Global Value Set by Following 'GET' API call.

```
services/data/v56.0/tooling/query/?q=select+Id,+DeveloperName+from+GlobalValueSet+WHERE+DeveloperName='MyPicklistName'
```

[image]

Now, Update the picklist using 'PATCH'

```
/services/data/v56.0/tooling/sobjects/GlobalValueSet/0Ntxxxxxxxxx
```

Use body format like this:

```
    {
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "GlobalValueSet",
    "url" : "/services/data/v56.0/tooling/sobjects/GlobalValueSet/0Ntxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "Metadata" : {
    "customValue" : [ 
        {"color": null,"default" : false,"description" : null,"isActive" : null,"urls":null,"valueName":"apiname1","label":"Label 1"}
    ],
    "description" : null,
    "masterLabel" : "MyGlobPick",
    "sorted" : false,
    "urls" : null
  },
  "FullName" : "MyGlobPick"
}
```

[image]

Comment: This mass-deactivates values - it doesn't delete them