# How to mass remove Managed package Global Picklist values

Tags: managed-package, package.xml, global-picklist, remove

I want to remove a  Global Picklist Value set with +200 values that is part of a managed package.

I have tried this solution : [Mass Delete Global Value Set Values](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173054/mass-delete-global-value-set-values)

It did not work out because I received the error : *Cannot modify managed object: entity=SharedPicklistDefinition, component=0NtXXXXXXX, field=DeveloperName, state=installed: newValue='abc', oldValue='xyz'.
errorCode: CANNOT_MODIFY_MANAGED_OBJECT*

The actual task is to change the API name of all 200+ values. For that I wanted to remove the old values and deploy the new set from an xml.
I still don't know what is best practice in this case.

Is there any way how it can be done ?

Thank you